# Nativescript Angular:Android fullscreen turned off on phone lock

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, fullscreen, nativescript-angular

I am using below code to make my app full screen but when someone locked his phone and than unlock it full screen turned off:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.goFullscreen();
  }
   private goFullscreen() {
    if (androidApp && device.sdkVersion >= '21') {
      const View = android.view.View;
      const window = androidApp.startActivity.getWindow();
      const decorView = window.getDecorView();
      decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
          View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
          View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
      );
    }
  }
```

is there any way to make app again full screen on phone unlock?

Comment: Try running the same code on Activity resume event.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the resume event and set full screen. You can also use it in a base component class for your page components.

```
import { on as applicationOn, resumeEvent, ApplicationEventData } from "tns-core-modules/application";

export class BaseComponent {

    constructor() {
        
        applicationOn(resumeEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
            //set full screen here
        });
     }

}
```